# <a> tag not getting edited by css code

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure why but my css isn't editing my linked text. I'm sure its a simple fix but I have had no luck so far.

**HTML (PHP)**

```
<a href="nextPage"> <?php echo $value  ?> </a>
```

**CSS**

```
a:hover, a:visited, a:link, a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please post more of your code as it may be something else stopping the CSS from working

Comment: What do you expect from the written code?

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what you want but from the small amount of code you've posted, it seems you didn't specify any style for your link's default state.

Comment: That it wont look like its hyperlinked.. currently it is not changing

Comment: @Jordanbaggs works for me http://jsfiddle.net/2JWbh/

Comment: have you forgotten to add normal "a" ? e.g. `a, a:hover, a:visited, a:link, a:active{ ...`

Comment: @Jordanbaggs, create a jsfiddle of your code

Comment: @Jordanbaggs  sure you included you css file correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you haven't specified a style for your link's default state. You should do the following :

```
a, a:hover, a:visited, a:link, a:active{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest at least testing out if you're CSS is actually being applied to the links. Perhaps try to add a class definition to the link, then referencing it in your css?

So the HTML might look like:

```
<a class="link" href="nextPage">
```

And your CSS might look like:

```
.link:hover, .link:visited, .link:link, .link:active{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight:normal;
```

}

Also I notice that your href="nextPage" attribute is not actually linking to a page. For example that should look like href="nextPage.html" or href="nextPage.php". I am wondering if without a proper target, the link is behaving differently? Maybe try creating an .html or .php file to test the link with, or link it to something like google or facebook. Just as a test :).